# How do I represent floating point numbers in hexadecimal values to use in c program?

Tags: c, hex

If `x` is variable defined as `float x`, how do I write a floating value as hexadecimal?

I don't know what should I do, please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Stricto sensu, your question does not make any sense. A floating number is not an integer so it cannot be represented in hexadecimal (base 16).

Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ at first.

Perhaps you want to output a float in hexadecimal *notation*. Then read documentation of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and, if your C implementation is C99 compliant, use `%a` like `printf("x=%a\n", x);` for example.

Maybe you want to output in hexadecimal the bitwise representation of your `float`. That would depend on the [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your machine (and on the fact that it uses [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for floating point representation), so the output won't be the same on a x86 and on an ARM. You might use a [`union` type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type):

```
union {
  unsigned u;
  float f;
} un;
un.f = x;
printf("%#x\n", un.u);
```

Of course, that makes sense only when `sizeof(unsigned)` is the same as `sizeof(float)` (and even in that case, the behavior is implementation defined).

Comment: I suspect the OP is looking for the 2nd, but you have all bases covered. Had not made use of `%a` before -- interesting, but a bit bewildered where I would use it outside of something like this.

Comment: I guess that OP don't know all the pitfalls of floating point (and neither do I). I have given some pointers.

Comment: Would `%a` output enough data by default for an exact roundtrip conversion? Does it make a difference that `x` is a `float` not a `double`?

Comment: That is actually a tricky question.... IIRC `float`-s are converted to `double`-s when passed as argument, but I leave you to check that (it could have changed between C90 & C99)

Answer (score 1):

In C99 the format to initialize a hexadecimal fp is `float a=0x1.abcdefp-5;`
The exponent is in decimal.

Comment: I m working in Ubuntu Linux using GCC would that work for me?